# Why are Images Imported as Planes Hidden by a Reference or Background Image?

Tags: image

When I import an image as plane with the alpha channel for transparency, and it is in front of a background or reference image I can't see the object (plane) to place or edit it? Why is this?

If this is a duplicate question please link / flag, I have looked but can't seem to find an answer... Thank you for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because *Images as Planes* addon automatically uses *Alpha Blend* mode.

Switch to *Alpha Clip* or *Alpha Hashed* and it will work as intended
(You need to be in *Eevee*, for these options to show up.)

[image]

Comment: Yes that does it Jachym thank you! In fact I looked back at my notes and had made a note about this to use Alpha Clip when working with the Images as Planes Add On, but strangely (frustratingly) in this scene the Blend Mode wasn't there in the Material Settings. After a bit, I finally worked out that I had set the Render Engine to Cycles, which doesn't allow one to then change the Blend Mode under Material Settings. If I switch it to Eevee, make the change to Alpha Clip and then back to Cycles it keeps the settings. Weird...

Comment: Yeah, it's not very intuitive. Anyways, mad props to you for keeping blender notes :).

Comment: Haha Yea It's the only way I can learn the software properly, otherwise I keep checking the same tutorials again and again and asking redundant questions here. Cheers for taking the time to upload the .gif super helpful!